# Managing system python2.7, brew python2.7, and brew python3 on the same machine

Tags: python, homebrew

My system python2.7 (`/usr/bin/python`) does not have `usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in its sys.path. As a result, various installed scripts that explicitly reference it fail (with, e.g., "ImportError: No module named appdirs").

For the most part, it's no problem, since I mostly use brew python 2.7 (at `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python`), which does point at it.

If I add that 2.7 `site-packages` to `$PYTHONPATH`, then `python3` picks it up and complains ("This package should not be accessible on Python 3").

If I don't, then the aforementioned scripts fail. Solutions include:

- Using pyenv / virtualenv. This is a bit inconvenient.
- Setting PYTHONPATH only while invoking those scripts. Unfortunately, some scripts explicitly unset PYTHONPATH.

Are there any obvious solutions I'm missing?

Comment: I would strongly recommend virtualenv. It's totally worth the inconvenience of having to set up the envs. Maybe check out virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: Thing is, for some packages I can only brew install, and brew doesn't deal with virtualenvs. Trying to pip install them results in compilation errors that I'd rather not deal with.